# How to stop fold expression function calls in the middle when a condition is met and return that value?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, fold-expression

I have functions `foo`, `bar`, `baz` defined as follows:

```
template <typename ...T>
int foo(T... t)
{
   return (bar(t), ...);
}

template <typename T>
int bar(T t)
{
    // do something and return an int
}

bool baz(int i)
{
    // do something and return a bool
}
```

I want my function `foo` to stop folding when `baz(bar(t)) == true` and return the value of `bar(t)` when that happens. How can I modify the above code to be able to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use short circuit `operator &&` (or `operator ||`):

```
template <typename ...Ts>
int foo(Ts... t)
{
    int res = 0;
    ((res = bar(t), !baz(res)) && ...);
    // ((res = bar(t), baz(res)) || ...);
    return res;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f6e9d97e35b3a82a)

Note:
`(baz(res = bar(t)) || ...);` would even be shorter, but less clear IMO.

Comment: Or equivalently `((res = bar(t), baz(res)) || ...)`

Comment: @Artyer: Yeah, I initially understand to continue while `baz(bar(t))` is `true`. So `&&` without negation.